# Can the last player in a trick win with Change Rage?

Tags: rage

In the game Rage, who wins the trick if the very last card played is a Change Rage card?  We're playing as though the person who played the Change Rage card is the winner since they changed the Trump color.

Does anyone have experience with this and if so, how did you determine the winner?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, the last player cannot win in this way. From the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_(trick-taking_card_game)#Bidding)

> The 14 Rage cards in the deck have black borders and, with the
>   exception of the Wild Rage card, **do not count as being of any suit and**
>   **therefore cannot win a trick**.

Honestly, I'm not really sure where the confusion is. The card changes the trump color. You then evaluate the other cards played on the trick, find the highest card of the new trump (or the highest of the led suit if there are no cards of the new trump), and it wins. The only player that can't possibly win the trick is the one that played the Change Rage.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, you're handling the scenario correctly.

I wasn't able to find any specific ruling for this. Rules As Written, though:

1. Change Rage "determines the trump color for this and any further tricks. The previous trump color is no longer valid for this trick."
2. The highest-number trump card in a trick always wins the trick.
3. I can't find any exceptions related to either of those two rules.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/55521/Fundex-Games-Rage.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_(trick-taking_card_game)#Bidding